# Invertir los bits de cada byte de una cadena

Tags: python, python-2.7, string, random

Tengo un byte string generado por el módulo Random de la biblioteca PyCrypto de esta manera:

```
c = Random.new().read(13)
```

Ahora bien, quiero invertir el valor de los bits que conforman `c` con el operador unario `~`, pero no puedo hacerlo al ser un byte string (por lo visto solo puedo utilizarlo con int).

Por ejemplo, si hipotéticamente el valor de los bits que conforman 'c' fuesen `1001010` querría tener un byte string cuyos bits fueran `0110101`...

¿Hay alguna manera de realizar la operación y seguir teniendo un byte string del mismo tamaño?

Answer (score 1):

No conozco mucho de `PyCrypto` pero entiendo que `Random.new().read(13)` te retorna una cadena de caracteres no UTF/multibyte, es decir un byte por caracter. Lo que puedes hacer entonces es invertir byte x byte de la siguiente forma:

```
from Crypto import Random
c = Random.new().read(13)

inv = "".join([chr(~ord(b) & 0xFF) for b in c])
```

Veamos:

- Recorremos cada caracter del string `c` mediante comprensión de listas, haciendo `[b for b in c]`
- Convertimos cada caracter al número que lo representa y lo invertimos `~ord(b)` esto nos daría un número negativo, como la idea es conseguir otro caracter hay que positivarlo usando la máscara `0xFF`
- Con el valor final volvemos a generar un caracter y con el método `join` juntamos nuevamente todo en un string "invertido".

Comment: En lugar de hacer el *"complemento a 2"* y luego positivar, es más directo usar un XOR: `ord(b) ^ 0xFF`. Además, en lugar de compresión de listas, quitando los corchetes funcionaría como *expresión generadora*, lo que evita la creación de una lista que no ibas a usar: `inv = "".join(chr(ord(b) ^ 0xFF) for b in c)`.

Comment: @ChemaCortes Funciona perfectamente esta solución. Ahora bien, si en lugar de invertir los bits lo que quiero es hacer un desplazamiento de los mismos con el operador `<<`... ¿cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: @KuroshD. Te recomendaría convertir la cadena a un entero y operar en él. La librería PyCrypto debería tener este tipo de ayudas (Si necesitas más ayuda, crea una nueva pregunta e intentaremos responder con detalle)